# JSTL foreach ArrayList Object from DAO Class won't work

Tags: jsp, foreach, arraylist, jstl, dao

Hello I wrote the following Code for a list output of different projects.

```
<%
List<ProjektDAO> projektListe = new ArrayList<ProjektDAO>();
projektListe = ProjektDB.getAllProjekte();
for(ProjektDAO i : projektListe)
{
%> Titel: <%= i.getName() %><br>
<%  
}
%>
```

everything is working fine here.

But my issue is to get this done with jstl

I wrote the following code:

```
<c:forEach items="${projektListe}" var="i">
    <p>Titel:</p> 
    <c:out value="${i.name}"></c:out> <br>
</c:forEach>
```

I don't think that's general jstl error, because I included the taglib
 `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>`
 and the jarfiles because this small test-code is working

```
    <c:out value="this is a jstl Test"></c:out>
```

I'm not sure if I should write ${i.name} or ${i.getName()} , but both versions don't work.

Is there something wrong with the tags or something else? I couldn't find any suggestions in StackOverFlow or elsewhere. 

Thank you for your help. Greetings Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL/JSTL only works with *scoped* value. You can bind `ProjektDB.getAllProjekte()` result to `request` or `session` into the service methods (doGet/doPost) of Servlet.

In servlet,

```
request.setAttribute("projektListe",ProjektDB.getAllProjekte());
```

and in JSP,

```
<c:forEach items="${projektListe}" var="i">
    <p>Titel:</p> 
    <c:out value="${i.name}"></c:out> <br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that I have to use a servlet in the background.